# Warning while accessing application's url : wildfly-9.0.2.Final,struts2-core-2.2.1.jar

Tags: struts2, wildfly

Enviornment -

1. Application server - wildfly-9.0.2.Final
2. struts jar - struts2-core-2.2.1.jar
3. Building tool - Ant
   My test application is working fine,but i am getting following warning while accessing the application.

   ```
   14:03:59,342 WARN  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager] (default task-1) Could not create JarEntryRevision for [vfs:/content/test.ear/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1]!: java.io.FileNotFoundException: vfs:/content/test.ear/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1 (No such file or directory)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager$JarEntryRevision.build(FileManager.java:307)
   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:145)
   14:03:59,643 WARN  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager] (default task-1) Could not create JarEntryRevision for [vfs:/content/test.ear/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/teststruts]!: java.io.FileNotFoundException: vfs:/content/test.ear/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/teststruts (No such file or directory)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager$JarEntryRevision.build(FileManager.java:307)
   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:145)
   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:105)
   ```

Following struts jar is present in WEB-INF/lib directory.

1.commons-io-1.3.2.jar*
2.freemarker-2.3.16.jar*
3.ognl-3.0.jar*
4.struts2-core-2.2.1.jar*
5.xwork-core-2.2.1.jar*
6.commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar*

Why this warning is coming, is there any compatibility issue?

Comment: Maybe an outdated info but take a look here - http://struts.apache.org/docs/jboss-5.html.

Comment: @Aleksandr M..Thankx for reply!! But i am using AS as wildfly-9.0.2.Final.

Comment: Fancy names... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly.

Comment: The second warn mentioned teststruts.jar. You might still have one of your class depending on teststruts lib. I would start by fixing this and retry.

Comment: struts2-core-2.2.1 can't fly anymore.